# Pytest coverage: run cov over multiple folders

Tags: python, pytest

My project has a structure like:

```
root/
  .coveragerc
  folder_a/
  folder_b/
  tests/
    folder_a/
    folder_b/
```

I would like to run `coverage` against `folder_a` and `folder_b`. Is possible to run it in a single command? Something like `pytest --cov=* tests/ --cov-report html`...

Comment: `pytest --cov=folder_a --cov=folder_b`?

Comment: Oh cool. Is possible to get folders name dynamically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamically" - if you're looking for a glob pattern like `--cov=folder_*`, then it depends on your shell whether it's expanded before passing the argument. `--cov` itself doesn't expand globs. For example, `--cov=folder_{a,b}` should work in bash, while `--cov=folder_*` not.

Comment: hoefling's comment is the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 30):

I'm posting the answer from @hoefling here because I didn't see the answer in the comment at first and saw it later when I looked at all the comments.

To specify coverage for multiple folders, provide the `--cov` multiple times:

```
pytest --cov=folder_a --cov=folder_b --cov=folder_c
```

Comment: Note that the documentation shows a syntax where you specify the path of the source AND the relative path of the tests within a single `--cov` argument. This appears to **not** be necessary and causes it to not work for me - just adding each source path as shown in the answer here does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

For example,

for a structure,

```
 > proj_folder
   - > tests_functional
   - > tests_unit
```

**Example**

```
$ pytest --cov=proj_folder proj_folder/tests_unit proj_folder/tests_functional
```

**Syntax**

```
$ pytest --cov=<proj_folder/package_name> <proj_folder>/tests_unit <proj_folder>/tests_functional
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work well. It runs coverage.py using pytest:

```
coverage run -m pytest
```

This was run at the project fodler. It was able to find the folder called tests, and run all the tests (which was split into multiple python files) within them. To see the report run:

```
coverage report
```