# How can I enforce 100% line coverage for test files in Python?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

In my project I don't test on different architectures / systems. For this reason every single line of the `tests/` folder should be executed. If it's not, it's a clear indicator that something went wrong.

I tried this:

```
pytest core/tests --cov --cov-report term-missing --cov-fail-under 100
```

But it fails as the whole project doesn't have 100% line coverage. I just want the `core/tests` folder to have 100% line coverage.

Bonus points if there is a way to check a single test, e.g.

```
pytest core/tests/test_demo.py --cov --cov-report term-missing --cov-fail-under 100
```

to only check if all lines of `test_demo.py` are covered.

Comment: Pytest coverage is specified by source path, not test path. You'll need to specify the path(s) to the source you want coverage on. To specify multiple paths: `pytest core/tests --cov=source_path_a --cov=source_path_b ...`. This answer explains it pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66323502/4583620.